# How to exclude from query's result in linq?

Tags: c#, linq

[image: First Query]

[image: Second Query]

In the first picture I have the result of first query, the highlighted part indicates the rows that would be excluded by applying the filter on the second query, in the second I have the result of query `select * from exlusion_table`

I have to make a change to the first query to have it exclude the items retrieved from the second query

the first query:

```
var u = from a in cx.VW_LIST
        where (a.PRJ == codPrj) && (a.DATE > date_ || a.DATE == null || date_ == null)
        && (x.Contains(a.CODE) || x.Count() == 0)
        select a)
```

the second query:

```
var y = from esc in cx.EXCLUSION select esc
```

The first query should be modified to exclude all the rows that have the value fcode = the fcode of the second query (in the case in which the fscode of the second query = null) or that (fcode = fcode of the second query && fscode = fscode of the second query )

Comment: What is the definition of `x`. You should consider using meaning ful names for your variables and aliases, it will make your code easier to read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches to this, one is to use `!` and `ANY()` to filter out records found within the other list, this will compile into `WHERE NOT EXISTS(_exclusion_)` filter expression

```
var excluded = cx.EXCLUSION.AsQueryable();

var query = from vw in cx.VW_LIST
            where vw.PRJ == codPrj
            where vw.DATE == null || date_ == null || vw.DATE > date_
            where !x.Any() || x.Contains(vw.CODE)
            where !excluded.Any(esc => vw.fcode == esc.fcode 
                                   && (esc.fscode == null || vw.fscode == esc.fscode))
            select vw;

var results = query.ToList();
```

The tricky element is the `null` for `fscode` in the excluded table, that needs to act as wildcard match, or negate the `fscode` comparison.

It is not necessary to split the `excluded` query out into it's own query, we could have referenced to the `cx.EXCLUSION` table directly and it would have exactly the same effect, this shows you an encapsulation technique for building the LINQ query in a way that you could easily increase the complexity of the exclusion lookup without creating a mess of your overall query.

You may also find need to conditionally build the query, this is where fluent syntax provides a more modular approach:

```
bool filterExcludedRecords = true;
...
var excluded = cx.EXCLUSION.AsQueryable();

var query = cx.VW_LIST.Where(vw => vw.PRJ == codPrj)
                      .Where(vw => vw.DATE == null || date_ == null || vw.DATE > date_)
                      .Where(vw => !x.Any() || x.Contains(vw.CODE));
if(filterExcludedRecords)
    query = query.Where(vw => !excluded.Any(esc => vw.fcode == esc.fcode 
                              && (esc.fscode == null || vw.fscode == esc.fscode)));

var results = query.ToList();
```

## OUTER JOIN

Another method is to use a `LFET OUTER JOIN` where the exclusion match is not found:

```
var excluded = cx.EXCLUSION.AsQueryable();

var query = from vw in cx.VW_LIST
            where vw.PRJ == codPrj
            where vw.DATE == null || date_ == null || vw.DATE > date_
            where !x.Any() || x.Contains(vw.CODE)
            from esc in excluded.Where(e => vw.fcode == e.fcode 
                                            && (e.fscode == null || vw.fscode == e.fscode))
                                .DefaultIfEmpty()
            where esc.fscode == null
            select vw;

var results = query.ToList();
```

The `WHERE NOT EXISTS` is often superior in terms of performance, `OUTER JOIN` may provide better response in an un-optimised table or when the number of rows in the exclusion list is significantly small and the number of rows in the main table is very large.

*I include this query option for completeness, it is not well known that you can create simple outer joins by adding a new `from` clause to the query.*

Answer (score 2):

You can use Any(). ie:

```
var u = from a in cx.VW_LIST
        where (a.PRJ == codPrj) 
           && (a.DATE > date_ || a.DATE == null || date_ == null)
           && (x.Contains(a.CODE) || x.Count() == 0)
           && (!cx.EXCLUSION.Any( y => x.fscode == y.fscode && x.fcode == y.fcode ))
        select a)
```

Comment: This comparison wont exclude the rows for the `fscode = null` criteria.

Comment: @ChrisSchaller, you can add null check. It is easy enough.